# Does HMRC Income Tax Returns for High Earners only apply to self employed individuals?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, self-assessment

[This article](https://www.gov.uk/income-tax-rates/income-over-100000) suggests that high earners (over £100,000) should file a self-assessment tax return:

> Income over £100,000
> Your Personal Allowance goes down by £1 for every £2 that your adjusted net income is above £100,000. This means your allowance is zero if your income is £125,140 or above.
>
> You’ll also need to do a Self Assessment tax return.
>
> If you do not usually send a tax return, you need to register by 5 October following the tax year you had the income.

But I don't understand where this applies. Is this only for self-employed, or would it apply for employed, receiving salary through PAYE?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not just for self-employed - PAYE employees with an income over £100k need to do a Self Assessement tax return (just as the quote you use indicates!).

You can confirm this with HMRC's [Check if you need to send a Self Assessment tax return](https://www.gov.uk/check-if-you-need-tax-return) interactive tool - entering "didn't work for myself", "didn't work as an off-payroll worker", "More than £100k" takes you to [here](https://www.gov.uk/check-if-you-need-tax-return/y/no/no/more-than-100-000) where it says "You need to send a Self Assessment tax return".